# How to create charts and formulas that update automatically in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to update formulas and charts daily in Excel.

I started as a working student recently and this is my first project for the logistic Team.

Currently we get the data from SAP which is then exported to Excel. Then we create formulas and charts manually.

They told me they do this every day even though, the formulas and charts are practically the same. The only difference is that the numbers change every day.

Now I want to find a way to update the formulas and charts daily on a specific time.
Also I want to create a Dashboard that does the same so they don't have to look at raw numbers anymore.

To Summarise the problem. I am looking for a way to create a dashboard that updates the formulas and charts automatically in Excel.

I am thankful for every advise.

Comment: Not much to go on. Do you have SAP Analysis installed? Which version of Excel? What have you tried? Could you edit your question & add some sample data? Also have a read of [Ask] & [MCVE].

Comment: You need to differentiate between entering data and displaying them. Formulas can do the latter but only the user can enter them - or a computer program. A dashboard isn't listed because it can only facilitate entering data by the user incl commands the user addresses to a computer program, such as clicking on a button. To write a program you need a language. VBA is popular for Excel. You would have to learn that. Dashboard design is a task only you can do. Once you start you may come to questions we can answer here. For now, it seems you don't have one.

Comment: Make a template with the raw data on one sheet and the formulae and charts on a second sheet. Then paste the fresh data on the data sheet and save as. Do check each time...